# How to make Nuget update page jquery references in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have an ASP.net solution with jquery and in some of the pages for example i have it referenced like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

The problem is that now Nuget updated the solution references to jquery to the version 2.0 and it hasnt updated the script references...this happened to other javascript references too...

How can i reference those scripts so when nuget updates them it updates the related page references too?

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of an indirect answer, but still a viable solution in many scenarios.

---

#### NuGet Updating Pages - Not Viable

I do not believe Nuget will be able to update anything in your pages.  I don't believe it has access to perform those types of operations.  Also, that'd probably be pretty insecure.

---

#### Using Bundling and Wildcards - Viable

This is the approach that I'd recommend.  It requires the Optimization package (which can be downloaded through NuGet).  It reduces the amount of requests made also, which is always nice.

Essentially, you create script "bundles" that allow you to combine multiple script files together (also works with CSS).  Below is an example of bundling that uses the `{version}` wildcard.

```
public class BundleConfig 
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) 
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
            .Include("Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui")
            .Include("Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
     }
}
```

Then you register the bundle in your Application_Start method in Global.asax.cs.

Lastly, you can replace your

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

with

```
<%: Scripts.Render("~bundles/jquery") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~bundles/jqueryui") %>
```

This will pick up the latest version of jQuery in your folders and utilize that, so you'll never have to change your script references again.

**Note**: the `"~/bundles/jquery"` string can be called whatever you want.
**Note**: This only works in .NET 4.5+ (Thanks [Kevin Johnsrude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1637126/kevin-johnsrude))
**Reference**: [Bundling and Minification in Web Forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx)

Also, while you didn't really ask about this, I feel obligated to mention it.  Those script references can be relocated to a MasterPage in the `<head>` block, which would allow you to reduce your code repetition (and align with the DRY principle).

Comment: Note that this only works in versions of .NET Framework >= 4.5.